# MySQL Relationship-problem

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have the following tables:
- news
- blogentries
- pictures
- comments

News, Blogentries and Pictures can be commented. I want to save all the comments in the comments-table.

My first idea was to make a referenceTo-column in the comments-table, but news, blogentries and picutres can have the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a column which tells you the type of object - news, blog entry, or picture.

You might want to consider using the [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) column type for this.